# What is the fastest way to match values in an array with other values in a dictinary, other than looping

Tags: c#

I have an array filled with protein id's and I have the protein name and id in a dictionary. I want to print every protein that it id is on the array. This is the method I am using to do that ,but it is not fast enough to do a large number of proteins.

```
string txt= "****** ID : {0} , Protien Name : {1} ******";
for (int i = 0; i < codonarray.Length; i++)
{
    if (codonarray[i] != null)
    {
        if (dictionaryproteins.TryGetValue(codonarray[i], out myvalue))
        { 
            Console.WriteLine(txt, codonarray[i], myvalue.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you it's the search that is slow and not the printing ?

Comment: No, The printing is slow.

Comment: Can you write it to a file instead of to the console?

Comment: What is "not fast enough"? How many elements are in the array and in the dictionary?

Comment: If printing to console is your bottleneck, how about creating the whole output in a `StringBuilder` and printing that once?

Comment: It would be great if you could provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Thank you I think the text file idea is the solution

Comment: @HassanAlsharif I turned my comment in to an answer so you can mark it accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary lookup you are using has O(1) performance (see: [Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)). This means that the time required for one lookup is near constant and does not depend on the size of the dictionary. It does not matter, whether you have 10 or 10,000,000 items in the dictionary.

You want to print each element of the array. So you need to loop through the array anyway. You could hide the loop in some LINQ construct, but the loop is still there and cannot be optimized away. This is a O(n) operation.

This means that you are already doing the matching in an optimum way. The combined performance (looping + lookup) is O(n). You cannot do better.

If you do I/O operations, then this is most probably the source of your performance problems. Try to minimize them. Use buffering, caching etc.

Print only a summary or only every n-th line. If printing alone takes too much time, how much time will it take to read the output?

Answer (score 0):

The console is relatively slow to print to. Write the data to a file instead of the console.

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] fileContent = File.ReadAllLines(@"Phrases\Phrases.txt");
```

then code what `filecontent` is, which in your case would the protein information.

An example of a file of 8,980 lines i use this for speech recognition to print to a text box and you can change it as you see fit. It prints really fast.

```
string[] fileContent0 = File.ReadAllLines(@"Phrases\Phrases.txt");
_recognizer.LoadGrammarAsync(new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(new Choices(fileContent0))));
```